# Basis matrix (basic variables index) with pulp python

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I am new to solving linear programming problems with python. At one stage, I need to find the basis matrix (basic indices variables). I am using pulp to solve my problems. Will be appreciated if any helps :).

Thanks,
Ali

Comment: It can give you duals and reduced cost. If no degeneracy that gives you the rows and columns that are basic (look for duals and reduced cost that are zero).

Comment: Thanks but my problem is highly degeneracy! In Matlab I used lp_solver and I found the basic indices but here not sure how to get it. But anyway thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: I don't think Pulp returns the basis status of variables and constraints. You may want to look at APIs of solvers directly. They typically provide this.